# ms reportviewer not show data on host server

Tags: reportviewer2008

I have created an Asp.net Project, I use MS Reportviewer for Reports of my project. When I place this project in my IIS by creating new Application in my main project. In it my reports Shows Correct but when I place this project on shared host by creating Virtual directory under my main project then No Data shows in it and the following error comes.

```
**Not Found**

The requested document was not found on this server.
```

In my webpage I call Report as Shown below

```
<div>

<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana"

Font-Size="8pt" Height="575px" Width="100%">

<localreport reportpath="Reports\rptChartofAccount.rdlc">

<datasources>

<rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource1"     Name="trialBalnace_vwBalanceSheet" />

</datasources>

</localreport>

</rsweb:ReportViewer>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server"
SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="AmsWeb.trialBalnaceTableAdapters.vwBalanceSheetTableAdapter" >

</asp:ObjectDataSource>

</div>
```

and in my Code Behind

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    ObjectDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("brid", Session("BrId"))

    Dim Param(0) As ReportParameter

    Param(0) =New ReportParameter("BrName", Session("BrName").ToString)

    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(Param)

    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh()

 End Sub
```

for ms reportviewer web.config file is as follows

```
<httpHandlers>
<remove path="*.asmx" verb="*"/>

----------

<add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false"/>
</httpHandlers>
<httpModules>
```

and Assembly added as following

```
<assemblies>
<clear/>
<add assembly="*"/>

<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>

<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
<add assembly="System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>

</assemblies>

<buildProviders>
<add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
</buildProviders>
```